# Why should you delete the 'obj' folder on every build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm new on a project and the building is quite slow.
Now I see as a postbuild event the next action for a lot of projects:

```
 <PostBuildEvent>rd "$(ProjectDir)obj" /S /Q</PostBuildEvent>
```

I've read that the `obj` folder keeps track of the builds so incremental builds can be faster, so I thought maybe this has something to do with it.

However, nobody in my team know why this is done, the removal of this folder, so I'm a bit hesitant to just remove the build action.

What can be a reason to perform this action?

Comment: What do you think of Christian's answer?  Do you have any questions now?

Comment: @starain Looks good, but I was hoping for some 'real' things that could benefit from the action, so I could make a decision wether that 'real' thing was needed or not.

Comment: I think the reason to delete obj folder is that, you don't want to 'enable' incremental build to make sure every files are newest.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things come to mind (all rather questionable by themselves):

- Custom build steps in the same, or - God forbid - other project that requires it (for the next build to succeed).
- A (misguided) attempt to preserve disk space (since all "precious" is in "bin" after the build you technically don't need "obj").
- A (misguided) attempt to implement "clean, clobber, etc."-semantics

One needs more information about the complete build system, other projects, etc. you have in place to find out more or better reasons - if at all ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The single possible reason to perform such kind of action is *lack of knowledge* about power of [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) utility.

I believe that target requirement (if it exist) could be achived another way, which will not omit the incremental build feature.

Try to find the author of that string in VCS you are using, and if author is unavailable or could not answer the question, warn your colleagues and remove it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Visual Studio where if you move the obj directory with the IntermediateOutputPath defined in the project file then the compiler still creates an empty obj directory any way. I do both myself, but with VS2010. If VS2015 has this fixed you may be able to remove it.

Comment: I used `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` (set for each configuration and platform combination, near the line with "<OutputPath>") and was able to move the `obj` folder away from the default location (up above the root, the folder with solution file), without Visual Studio 2012 creating an empty `obj` folder.